# Почему при удалении некоторых вопросов удаляется и пользователь?

Tags: обсуждение

Пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/456919/178988

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому что пользователь был анонимным. Он не создавал учётной записи, чтобы задать вопрос.

Comment: В комментариях обращаются к пользователю `@Katerina Savchuk`. Разве анонимный пользователь может настроить отображаемое имя?