# Когда удаляется пользователь?

Tags: поддержка, удаление-профиля

[Вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/488723) был задан пользователем [Соня Васильева](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/200843/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d0%92%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b0), причём даже с аватаркой:
[image]

Вроде не похоже на [незарегистрированного пользователя](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1495/178988), но после удаления вопроса пользователь тоже исчез - написано `user200843`, а страница профиля не существует.

Почему так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Учетная запись может быть удалена двумя способами:

- Автоматически, когда в системе срабатывает заданное условие, в том числе в случае запроса на удаление профиля от участника с низкой репутацией.
- Вручную, когда модератор от компании может принять однозначное решение, что данному участнику не место на сайте, либо по запросу самого участника.

#### Почему учетная запись была удалена?

Данная учетная запись пользователя была удалена вручную модератором от компании (мной), потому что одним из важнейших условий построения сообщества является поддержание здорового окружения. Окружение Stack Overflow на русском – атмосфера знаний. Если новые пользователи попадая из поисковика будут натыкаться на вопросы, не относящиеся к тематике сайта или не отвечающие стандартам качества, то вряд ли захотят создавать учётную запись. Аналогично и с существующими участниками сообщества – мы (как минимум, говорю за себя) ассоциируем себя с сообществом.

#### Удалять или не удалять?

В случае появления вопроса, не удовлетворяющего качеству сайта, следует сделать все нижеперечисленное:

- Удалить вопрос,
- Отправить личное сообщение автору, если это не первое сообщение не удовлетворяющее условием сообщества,
- Заблокировать доступ к учетной записи участника, если при публикации сообщения были допущены грубые нарушения правил (например, оскорбления),
- Удалить учетную запись, если вероятность публикации сообщений удовлетворяющих условию сообщества крайне низкая.

На мой взгляд, ассоциация Stack Overflow со школьной геометрией не укладывается в картину мира среднестатистического разработчика, а самим школьникам не место в профессиональном сообществе программистов.

Comment: Ещё одна причина - когда зарегистрировался человек младше 13 лет. Тогда terms of service предписывают удалить учётку. Даже есть соответствующий  шаблон письма в transifex.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а как определяется что человек младше 13 лет? :-) просто галочкой? типа да, я младше 13?

Comment: @Grundy: в профиле есть поле для ввода дня рождения. Впрочем, как и везде в интернете, это ограничение легко обходится — достаточно не указывать дату рождения. Но если пользователь честно укажет и окажется, что он младше необходимого возраста, то, судя по всему, придётся отказать ему в доступе.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, вот интересно получается :-) честно указал - удалили, указал неверно либо не указал - оставили

Comment: @Grundy: это интернет. )